# Using GSON to JSON > POJO

Tags: java, json, gson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing JSON to Java POJO's using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949986/parsing-json-to-java-pojos-using-gson)

I'm trying to map this JSON to a POJO with GSON:

```
{
"get_lists": [
    {
        "Solution": [
            {
                "A05": "Herhalingsbezoek vereist"
            },
            {
                "A03": "Melding met oh verholpen"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Problem": [
            {
                "R07B": "Aandrijving"
            },
            {
                "R07C": "Coating"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However, both the keys and values inside of the solution and problem can vary, and I haven't had to deal with this before.

Answer (score 3):

If your keys don't vary too much you can make a class having all the desired fields ?

If not you have those solutions :

- use a [custom Deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).
- decode as a raw collection : here's [an example very similar to your problem](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java).
- deserialize your solutions using `HashMap<String, String>[]` :

  ```
  public class ListItem {
      public HashMap<String, String>[] Solution;
      public HashMap<String, String>[] Problem;
  }

  public class Message {
      public ListItem[] get_lists;
  }
  ```

That's a little heavy but it avoids the use of custom deserializer.

Comment: they vary in the sense that, keys and values may be added or altered.

Comment: Im trying your HashMap solution, and I think im getting them correctly in my get_lists as an array of Lists, but im having trouble mapping them to HashMaps in ListItem.

Answer (score 0):

According to me Given Structure represents below POJO

```
class OuterObject
{
private List<MyObject> getLists;
 }

private class MyObject
{
private List<MyKeyValuePair> myList;
}

private class MyKeyValuePair
{
private String key;
private String value;
}
```

May this help

Comment: Thanks, I understand how GSON maps it to POJO's like this, but I actually dont know the keys. Both keys and values can change at anytime.